# Twint (python library) and Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I am using a python library to pull data from social media. I am trying to analyze it in elasticsearch/kibana. I have elasticsearch and kibana set up and they are working fine. The python library is pulling data fine also, but When I try to index my data I get the following error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>twint -es localhost:9200 -u twitterusername --limit 10
[+] Indexing to Elasticsearch @ localhost:9200
CRITICAL:root:twint.get:User:
```

Is something wrong with my system?

Comment: you should share more detail.

Comment: Edited the original post

Comment: For what it's worth, I receive the same error message. Sometimes I first receive the error message and then I receive the output, sometimes, I just receive the error message.

Comment: Yes, after going into Kibana I saw that it sometimes saves the output. There is a definitely some kind of communication error going on. Thank you for your reply!